# create switch with labels element

Tags: html, css, button, switch-statement

I want to create switch like this, where i can choose only one option from two 
[image]

[image]

I could do this one, but cant figure out how to overlay them.
.

```
 <button>Курьер</button><button>Самовывоз</button>
```

css

```
  button{
                margin-top: 15px; 
                width: 50%;
                height: 25px;
                border-radius: 20px;
                border: none;
                background:
                linear-gradient(to right, #2BD563, #0183D3) no-repeat; 
                color:#fff;
                .reg;
                text-transform: uppercase;
    }
```

anyone who can help?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a class for active button and add the class via Javascript.

Comment: @AbdullahAlemadi what about overlaying each other, one should be "above" the second. In my case they seem like in row.

Comment: aha I see what you want. I will answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of divs,
have a main container div with a div inside for the colour bar and 2 more divs for text:

```js
let pos = 0;
document.getElementById("container").onclick = function() {
  if (pos == 0)
    pos = 100;
  else
    pos = 0;
  document.getElementById("colour").style.left = pos + "px";
}
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 200px;
  background: grey;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

#colour {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  background: green;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: left 0.2s;
}

#text1 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

#text2 {
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="colour"></div>
  <div id="text1">hello</div>
  <div id="text2">goodbye</div>
</div>
```

By controlling the "left" property of the colour bar you can animate it, I included some quick JS to show you how you might do something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one `checkbox` to toggle between buttons. And to position first button over second one you can use negative `z-index` on second button.

```css
.field {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 0;
}

#check {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
button {
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-radius: 40px;
  padding: 3px 35px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
#check:checked ~ button:last-of-type,
#check ~ button:first-of-type{
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
#check:checked ~ button:first-of-type {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
button:last-of-type {
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" name="" id="check">
  <button>Курьер</button>
  <button>Самовывоз</button>
</div>
```